# getElementByID Not working because field is in some sort of frame, how do I access it?

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyname

Please go to this page real quick and hit the login at the top right:

Here's the link: http://forums.gamesalad.com

I'm trying to pre-fill these two fields that pop up. They seem to be in some sort of frame. I am unable to access the fields using getElementByID (or any getElement for that matter). How can I access these two fields using javascript?

NOTE: (don't worry about firing the javascript, just getting access to the fields).

Here's my current code:

```
document.getElementById('login-dialog-email').value = 'the user name';
```

Comment: What page are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, almost forgot to add it.

Comment: Hi again, the next thing you need to add is the code that you're trying to use to access those fields. This gives us a place to start and also makes it look like you've attempted it yourself/done the research. Good luck!

Comment: @ManOx The input field isn't in any frame, I mean, it's in a `div` that has the `id` of "frame," but it's not in any HTML frame.

Comment: @JonathanSampson So then is there any special way I should be accessing it? Because like I said, the getElement isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your HTML in a debugger, like the Chrome Debugger, you'll see that you have two instances of the input elements with id="login-dialog-email".

The W3C spec says that only one instance of an id attribute can be used in a single HTML document, and browser vendors implement this spec in a manner where the behavior is considered to be undefined if more than one id attribute of the same value is on the page.

In my experience, this really only affects the second instance of the element with said id, and if you do a search for login-dialog-email and examine which element gets  highlighted, you'll see that the second instance is the one that represents your form.

Remove the first instance, or use a unique id, and then you'll be able to target the element.

The first instance of this login field appears to be part of a template that is hidden on the page.

```
<div id="login-form-template" style="display: none">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://auth.gamesalad.com/auth/signIn" class="dialog dialog-form" id="common-login-form" method="post">
   ...

    <li class="email">
        <label for="login-dialog-email">
        Email:
          <input id="login-dialog-email" name="emailAddress" type="text" value=""></input>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class="password">
        <label for="login-dialog-password">
        Password:
          <input id="login-dialog-password" name="password" type="password" value="">
        </label>
    ...
```

The second instance of this field actually appears inside the fancybox, which is where the **actual HTML is located that you are trying to target.**

```
<div id="fancybox-content" style="border-top-width: 10px; border-right-width: 10px; border-bottom-width: 10px; border-left-width: 10px; width: 300px; height: 233px; "><div style="width:300px;height:auto;overflow: auto;position:relative;">
   <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://auth.gamesalad.com/auth/signIn" class="dialog dialog-form" id="common-login-form" method="post">
   ...
   <li class="email">
       <label for="login-dialog-email">
         Email:
         <input id="login-dialog-email" name="emailAddress" type="text" value="">
       </label>
   </li>
   <li class="password">
     <label for="login-dialog-password">
       Password:
       <input id="login-dialog-password" name="password" type="password" value="">
     </label>
   <span>
...
```

Thus, even if the site owner were trying to target these fields from the page, he/she would have the same problem.

The solution to this problem is to use className attributes within any template. This ensures that all of the fields can be targeted via DOM methods.

However, this doesn't mean that you can't still target the elements:

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("email")[2].
    getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "test@example.com";
```

**jQuery:**

The site *is* using jQuery, so you may also be able to use this:

```
$('input[name="emailAddress"]').val( "test@example.com" );
```

Comment: I don't own this site, and have no access to the servers hosting the files. Is there any way to do it without editing the id's?

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but how can I use the class to specify which field I'm want to access?

Comment: @ManOx - Sorry. Took me a minute. My RAW JavaScript skills have been slightly weakened by jQuery :)  You can use the getElementsByClassName selector and then target the third item in the collection, then use getElementsByTagName to get the input element.

Comment: THANKS SOOOO Much this will make my users (including me) soooo Happy :)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help :) If you're friendly with the site owner, you may want to suggest they use class names in the templates they use with FancyBox. They may one day have more unexpected behavior themselves when trying to target duplicate id's. Good luck!

Comment: Yep I will send them a message, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you have the same id `login-dialog-email` for password and email input box. javascript is confused when you try to assign value. Assign different id's and you are good to go.